# r- how to shift a varying number of NAs from the bottom to the top of columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, na

For example, I'd like to take this:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1:6), c(6,5,4,3,NA,1), c(1,NA,3,4,NA,6)))
dat
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  6  5  4  3 NA  1
3  1 NA  3  4 NA  6
```

And create this:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,NA,3,4,NA,6), c(6,2,4,3,NA,1), c(1,5,3,4,5,6)))
dat
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1 NA  3  4 NA  6
2  6  2  4  3 NA  1
3  1  5  3  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
dat[] <- apply(dat,2, function(x) c(x[is.na(x)], x[!is.na(x)]))
dat
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1  1 NA  3  4 NA  6
#2  6  2  4  3 NA  1
#3  1  5  3  4  5  6
```

Or a better method would be

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) c(x[is.na(x)], x[!is.na(x)]))
```

Or using `data.table` (suggested by @David Arenburg)

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)[, names(dat) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
                         c(x[is.na(x)], x[!is.na(x)]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
move_NAs_to_end <- function(v) { c(v[!is.na(v)], v[is.na(v)]) }

apply(dat, 2, move_NAs_to_end)
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
[1,]  1  2  3  4  5  6
[2,]  6  5  4  3 NA  1
[3,]  1 NA  3  4 NA  6
```